# How can I set http2 pseudo headers when using curl

Tags: curl, http2

I'm trying to add an `http2` pseudo header to a request I'm making with curl. I tried:

```
curl -v -H ":test: value" https://example.com
```

And other header names that start with `:`. They all fail with

> curl: (55) Failed sending HTTP request

here's the full curl verbose output:

```
*   Trying 93.184.216.34:443...
* Connected to example.com (93.184.216.34) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Los Angeles; O=Internet�Corporation�for�Assigned�Names�and�Numbers; CN=www.example.org
*  start date: Jan 13 00:00:00 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Feb 13 23:59:59 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "example.com" matched cert's "example.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multiplexing
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* Failed sending HTTP request
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
curl: (55) Failed sending HTTP request
```

Is this possible with curl?

Answer (score 0):

Try with curl-impersonate version, that mimics a real browser:

> When you use an HTTP client with a TLS website, it first performs a TLS handshake. The first message of that handshake is called Client Hello. The Client Hello message that most HTTP clients and libraries produce differs drastically from that of a real browser.

> If the server uses HTTP/2, then in addition to the TLS handshake there is also an HTTP/2 handshake where various settings are exchanged. The settings that most HTTP clients and libraries use differ as well from those of any real browsers.

> For these reasons, some web services use the TLS and HTTP handshakes to fingerprint which client is accessing them, and then present different content for different clients. These methods are known as TLS fingerprinting and HTTP/2 fingerprinting respectively. Their widespread use has led to the web becoming less open, less private and much more restrictive towards specific web clients
>
> With the modified curl in this repository, the TLS and HTTP handshakes look exactly like those of a real browser.

https://github.com/lwthiker/curl-impersonate

```
git clone https://github.com/lwthiker/curl-impersonate.git
cd curl-impersonate
./configure
make chrome-build # or make firefox-build
```

Example for `firefox`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Find the directory of this script
dir=${0%/*}

# The list of ciphers can be obtained by looking at the Client Hello message in
# Wireshark, then converting it using the cipherlist array at
# https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/lib/vtls/nss.c
#"$dir/curl-impersonate-ff" \
/home/me/curl-impersonate/build_ff/curl-7.84.0/src/curl-impersonate-ff \
    --ciphers aes_128_gcm_sha_256,chacha20_poly1305_sha_256,aes_256_gcm_sha_384,ecdhe_ecdsa_aes_128_gcm_sha_256,ecdhe_rsa_aes_128_gcm_sha_256,ecdhe_ecdsa_chacha20_poly1305_sha_256,ecdhe_rsa_chacha20_poly1305_sha_256,ecdhe_ecdsa_aes_256_gcm_sha_384,ecdhe_rsa_aes_256_gcm_sha_384,ecdhe_ecdsa_aes_256_sha,ecdhe_ecdsa_aes_128_sha,ecdhe_rsa_aes_128_sha,ecdhe_rsa_aes_256_sha,rsa_aes_128_gcm_sha_256,rsa_aes_256_gcm_sha_384,rsa_aes_128_sha,rsa_aes_256_sha \
    -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0' \
    -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' \
    -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' \
    -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
    -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
    -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' \
    -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' \
    -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: none' \
    -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' \
    -H 'TE: Trailers' \
    --http2 --false-start --compressed \
    "$@"
```

Comment: Good to know about `curl-impersonate`. I tried it, and it seems to ignores the custom pseudo header.

Comment: Maybe you are wrong passing it to cURL, as I said, it's like a real browser query. If the answer was good to know, maybe deserve a vote up